# Using PIR to activate electromagnets on a relay module

Tags: arduino

So I'm running the PIR off the 3.3v pin of the arduino, the gnd pin of the arduino, and then into input 9. I adjusted my code to the website but it still doesn't work. I want the relays to be on when the PIR is low and then turn off with PIR is high. I also need the PIR to wait for at least 5 seconds before registering another input.

```html
#define RELAY_ON 1
#define RELAY_OFF 0

#define Relay_1  2  // Arduino Digital I/O pin number
#define Relay_2  3
#define Relay_3  4
#define Relay_4  5
#define Relay_5  6  
#define Relay_6  7


/*-----( Declare Variables )-----*/
int waittime; // Delay between changes

int state = LOW;             // by default, no motion detected
int val = 0;                 // variable to store the sensor status (value)
int pirPin = 9;    //the digital pin connected to the PIR sensor's output



void setup()   /****** SETUP: RUNS ONCE ******/
{
  waittime = 1000;
  pinMode(pirPin, INPUT);     // initialize sensor as an input
  Serial.begin(9600);        // initialize serial
    
//-------( Initialize Pins so relays are active at reset)----
  digitalWrite(Relay_1, RELAY_ON);
  digitalWrite(Relay_2, RELAY_ON);
  digitalWrite(Relay_3, RELAY_ON);
  digitalWrite(Relay_4, RELAY_ON);  
  digitalWrite(Relay_5, RELAY_ON);
  digitalWrite(Relay_6, RELAY_ON);
//---( THEN set pins as outputs )----  

  digitalWrite(pirPin, LOW);  
  pinMode(Relay_1, OUTPUT);   
  pinMode(Relay_2, OUTPUT);  
  pinMode(Relay_3, OUTPUT);  
  pinMode(Relay_4, OUTPUT);    
  pinMode(Relay_5, OUTPUT);   
  pinMode(Relay_6, OUTPUT);  
  delay(4000); //Check that all relays are active at Reset
  
}//--(end setup )---


void loop()   /****** LOOP: RUNS CONSTANTLY ******/
{

val = digitalRead(pirPin);   // read sensor value
if (val == HIGH) {           // check if the sensor is HIGH   
//---( Turn all 8 relays ON in pairs)---  

  digitalWrite(Relay_1, RELAY_OFF);// set the Relay OFF
  digitalWrite(Relay_2, RELAY_OFF);// set the Relay OFF
  delay(waittime);              // wait for a second  
  
  digitalWrite(Relay_3, RELAY_OFF);// set the Relay OFF 
  digitalWrite(Relay_4, RELAY_OFF);// set the Relay OFF
  delay(waittime);
  
  digitalWrite(Relay_5, RELAY_OFF);// set the Relay OFF
  digitalWrite(Relay_6, RELAY_OFF);// set the Relay OFF
  delay(5000);              // wait see all relays ON  
  
  if (state == LOW) {
      Serial.println("Motion detected!"); 
      state = HIGH;       // update variable state to HIGH
    }
  } 

  else {
    
//---( Turn all 8 relays OFF in pairs)---

  digitalWrite(Relay_1, RELAY_ON);// set the Relay ON
  digitalWrite(Relay_2, RELAY_ON);// set the Relay ON
  delay(waittime);   
  
  digitalWrite(Relay_3, RELAY_ON);// set the Relay ON
  digitalWrite(Relay_4, RELAY_ON);// set the Relay ON
  delay(waittime);
  
  digitalWrite(Relay_5, RELAY_ON);// set the Relay ON
  digitalWrite(Relay_6, RELAY_ON);// set the Relay ON
  delay(10000);              // wait see all relays OFF
  
    
       
       
 if (state == HIGH){
        Serial.println("Motion stopped!");
        state = LOW;       // update variable state to LOW
       }
     }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

When things don't work the way I expect them to, I always look at the wiring first.  Write some simple test code that does nothing but print the state of your PIR's signal pin.  Does it go high when you expect it to?  Does it go low when you expect it to?  If not, you have a wiring problem.  Get that straightened out before you even think about the rest of the programming.

As for the wiring...you didn't mention a pull-up resistor in your description - most PIR modules (at least the ones I've worked with) require a pull-up resistor on their signal pin to pull the output high when there is no signal.  Maybe you have one and just didn't mention it, but if not then that's likely your problem - without a pull-up resistor, your output is floating and your device will not work the way you expect it to. That said, most Arduino boards (you didn't say which one you are using) have internal pull-ups on the digital pins, but you have to enable them by doing:

```
pinMode(pin, INPUT);      
digitalWrite(pin, HIGH);
```

You are setting your signal pin LOW in your setup() routine, which turns off the internal pull-up resistor.  Change that to HIGH to turn it on, then you can avoid adding an external resistor.

Also, are you sure your PIR module runs on 3.3V?  Some require 5V.  Check its data sheet to be sure.